# User Defined Language Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I'm stuck in defining my language in Notepad++ for syntax-highlighting.
I would like to define different colors for different output files that i get from a software. The usual string is:

```
@--MESSAGE ssksjdjsksl
@ kdkdkdkdkdk
@ kdkdjdj
   23 ghgjgh
@--ERROR ffjjfkfk
@ djdjdj

@--WARNING SJSJ
@ djdjdjdj
```

What i would like is that Notepad++ recognize the type of string (MESSAGE or ERROR or WARNING) and color the line till it found the @ symbols, and go back to normal when the @ symbol disappear. If possible, it would also use a different color for each message type.

I tried with the delimiters but there isn't an unique character that exit the message, so I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Well every @ is on a new line

Comment: The title is a bit vague

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve this thing with User Defined Language in Notepad++. Most advanced users can achieve this by modifying Notepad++ source files and adding own lexer there.

However, there is a **workaround** which might (or might not) help you:

Define highlighting of the following symbols:

```
@--ERROR
@--WARNING
@--MESSAGE
```

You can assign different color (or better: different **background color**) to each. These highlights will catch your eyes as message starting points.

Additionally you can make words like `error` appear in red anywhere in text.